# Clion + MinGW отлючение командной строки при билде

Tags: mingw, clion

После билда проекта в .exe файл и его последующего запуска появляется командная строка, которая мне не нужна. Какие нужно установить параметры сборки, чтобы она не появлялась?

Заранее благодарю за ответ